# How to bind IValueConverter to itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, ivalueconverter

I need to pass converter itself as binding. Does anyone know how i can do this ?

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Converter="{Binding <!--I need to pass here converter from xaml, not from viewmodel-->"
            Mode="OneWay"
            Path="DataContext.Item"
            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: What converter? How about a more complete example, I'm struggling to work out what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could write a converter that hands off the `Convert` call to other converters according to... I don't know what. Tough without bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of `Binding` *cannot* be bound. if you have the converter defined in XAML resources you can use `StaticResource` directly to reference it.